# JTextPane and undo manager style change

Tags: java, swing, styles, jtextpane, styleddocument

**My situation**: I have a *JTextPane* with its own syntax highlighting. I have it set so that when the user stops typing, it updates the style in the text using the setCharacterAttributes() method.

**My Issue**: When these updates to the style are not performed, the undo manager works as expected. But when I do use it, the undo manager counts those style changes as actual undo-able actions! Meaning hitting Ctrl+z *(I have it bound to undo when pressed)* it just un-colors the last character i typed. Rather than actually removing/undoing it.

How would I get it so undo-ing and redo-ing only affects text changes and not style/font changes in my *StyledDocument*?

Thank you.

Comment: Please post a minimal version of your code so that we know your exact scenario.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to make use of `addEdit` or the `Significant` attribute as explained by the `UndoManager`:

> The UndoManager makes use of isSignificant to determine how many edits
>   should be undone or redone. **The UndoManager will undo or redo all
>   insignificant edits** (isSignificant returns false) **between the
>   current edit and the last or next significant edit**. addEdit and
>   replaceEdit can be used to treat multiple edits as a single edit,
>   returning false from isSignificant allows for treating can be used to
>   have many smaller edits undone or redone at once. Similar
>   functionality can also be done using the addEdit method.

Sources:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/undo/UndoableEdit.html

Comment: I tried this and ran into the issue that I could only undo once, and not undo. 

Rather than fixing the problem I just created my own custom undo manager class, which works pretty well. Thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of unsuccessful attempts I figured out a solution. Basically I use a javax.swing.text.PlainDocument.PlainDocument(), call it "undoDoc", together with the standard javax.swing.text.StyledDocument, call it "editDoc"; keep their textual content aligned and connect the UndoManager with the undoDoc; on any unodo/redo operation I copy the entire text from undoDoc to editDoc any analize again the text for syntax highlighting.
You find the full code here: https://github.com/usnasoft/usnalib2/blob/main/src/main/java/it/usna/swing/SyntaxEditor.java
An usage example is here: https://github.com/usnasoft/usnalib2/blob/main/src/main/java/it/usna/examples/SyntacticTextEditor.java